# Cython cimport and __init__.pyx buggy?

Tags: import, cython

It seems like compiling an `__init__.pyx` that contains a `cimport` statement is buggy.

This is my folder-structure:

```
DrawAPI\
    __init__.pyx
    utils.pxd
```

The `__init__.pyx`:

```
cimport utils
```

Compiling the `__init__.pyx` with cython gives me that `utils.pxd` could not be found. But renaming `__init__.pyx` to any other name, like `foo.pyx` for instance

```
DrawAPI\
    foo.pyx
    utils.pxd
```

and then compiling `foo.pyx` works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a directory contains an `__init__.py` or `__init__.pyx` file it is assumed to be a package directory. So in your example the utils module is assumed to belong to the package `DrawAPI` and its FQMN is `DrawAPI.utils`

However, if `DrawAPI` is the current directory you're running the compiler from, and you haven't added DrawAPI to the include path the `utils.pxd` won't be found (as you have discovered...)

If you intend utils to be a top-level module then you will have to move it somewhere else where there is no `__init__.pyx` file.

If you intend it to reside in a package, then cd to the directory containing `DrawAPI` and compile from there.

Comment: Lol, of course. Haven't thought about this. Unfortunately, relative import isn't supported yet, but using `from DrawAPI cimport utils` works just fine. :) +50 bounty worth & +1